# SSH connection speed drops after some time of inactivity

Tags: ssh, file-transfer

I use MC to transfer working files from my Ubuntu 14.04 to other Linux hosts (mostly CentOS5).

Shell link is opened by F9->R->H(shell link)->${host}->Enter combination (in MC).

Then I can copy files to the host.

After some time of inactivity (possibly an hour or more) I'm still able to navigate with the panel and transfer files but transfer speed becomes extremely slow.

Is this MC bug or SSH client/server settings? Where to dig?

MC version: 3:4.8.11-1 (amd64)

Comment: This is probably a firewall setting. If so, there's nothing you can do to remove the problem unless you can find which firewall and convince its administrator. You may still be able to work around the problem by telling SSH to send more keepalive messages (try adding `ServerAliveInterval 300` to your `~/.ssh/config`).

Comment: What happens if you enable pings? On the client, in ~/.ssh/config, add two lines: `ServerAliveInterval 30`, `ServerAliveCountMax 4`; or on the server in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, add two lines `ClientAliveInterval 30`, `ClientAliveCountMax 4`

Comment: I've set `ServerAliveInterval 300` in `~/.ssh/config` and it  has fixed the issue. Thank you guys for your response!